# How to prevent the moving of line numbers in display-line-numbers-mode

Tags: line-numbers, hideshow

Sorry about the title, I don't know how to describe it better.

Using `display-line-numbers-mode` with `hs-hide-all` to edit a Common Lisp file, I see the line number moving to the right, which is quite distracting and annoying. How could I prevent that from happening?

Notice line number 32

Normal:

[image: Normal]

Moved to right:

[image: Moved]

A sample:

```
;;;please add 26 empty lines in bar yourself, and then `hs-hide-all`
(defun bar ()
  ())

(defun test ()
  ())
```

You may say there are too many empty lines, but even if these lines are dispersed to other functions, the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be an emacs bug, see [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=54091)

should be fixed in 28-branch